# How to add Core Plot as static library to Mac app?

Tags: macos, xcode5, core-plot

I am working on a Mac App project using Xcode 5.0.2. Currently Core Plot 1.1 is integrated in the project. I did this following the instructions on the Core Plot [project page](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications): The Core Plot source code is integrated in my project and compiles alongside with my app.

Since I switched from Xcode 4 to 5 I have trouble starting my app. The receipt validation code that runs at startup cannot verify the apps receipt any more. The console shows a hint that the app is not signed properly:

> storeagent[329]: Unsigned app (/Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gvgullbzaekzujejuhfssrnmmmit/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app).

I found a [hint](http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/) that there is a problem signing nested bundles like Core Plot when using Xcode 5 on Mavericks.

Because of this I would like to integrate Core Plot as static library instead of as nested bundle. However the instructions on the Core Plot page (see link above) only describes this option for iOS projects.

Is it possible to use Core Plot as static library in an Mac App project as well? What would be the necessary steps to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably figured out a way to do this already, but as I was struggling with the same thing myself and the steps, while simple, don't seem to be explained anywhere I thought I would do so as an answer here.  As you mentioned, this is not explained on the [CorePlot Mac Setup Page](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications), so it may cause complications or become obsolete down the road, but it is working for me as of right now.  Steps are:

1. Download the latest [CorePlot release](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases)
2. Copy the file Binaries/MacOS/CorePlot.framework into your project (drag and drop or by using "Add files to ..."

   - Make sure you enable "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)"
   - Make sure the new framework is added to the applications target membership
3. Set up the framework to be copied during build

   - Under Build Phases, add a Copy Files phase if there is none
   - Change the destination to "frameworks"
   - Drag the CorePlot.framework file from the Project Navigator into the file list